# Clickhouse howto calculate sum of intervals PAUSE -> UNPAUSE?

Tags: clickhouse

Few month ago I try to analyze data in clickhouse and I like it. It very fast.
Today I have a user log. And I need to calculate sum of pause time for each user.
What I do:
I select log for one day using where. And receive table like this:

| time | user | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-24 11:39:21 | user1 | PAUSE |
| 2021-09-24 11:39:21 | user2 | PAUSE |
| 2021-09-24 11:41:53 | user2 | UNPAUSE |
| 2021-09-24 11:41:53 | user1 | UNPAUSE |

For each user I have several events 'PAUSE' and several events 'UNPAUSE'. Have time and username.

There is a nuance: Sometimes I have count(PAUSE) != count(UNPAUSE) for each user.

I need to calculate sum of time in all intervals in seconds (PAUSE -> UNPAUSE)
I see result table like this:

| user | sum_pause_time |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 345 |
| user2 | 436 |

that is my select:

```html
select
    user,
    sum_unpause - sum_pause as sum_pause_time
from
(
select
    user,
    sum(CASE
        WHEN event == 'PAUSE' THEN toUnixTimestamp(time)
    END) as sum_pause,
    sum(CASE
        WHEN event == 'UNPAUSE' THEN toUnixTimestamp(time)
    END) as sum_unpause
from
    queue_log_copy
where
    toStartOfDay(time) >= (toStartOfDay(now()) - interval 1 day)
group by
    user
)
```

But something wrong in it 
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate diff between PAUSE and UNPAUSE through arrayMap method, you just need to group values as arrays before. Also in if we check if previous event is PAUSE and current UNPAUSE

```
(i > 1) AND (ex = 'UNPAUSE') AND ((e[i - 1]) = 'PAUSE')
```

Some example to check

```
     CREATE TABLE test
        (
            `time` DateTime,
            `user` Int64,
            `event` String
        )
        ENGINE = Memory
    insert into test values ('2021-09-24 11:39:21', 1, 'PAUSE')
    insert into test values ('2021-09-24 11:39:21', 2, 'PAUSE')
    insert into test values ('2021-09-24 11:41:53', 2, 'UNPAUSE')
    insert into test values ('2021-09-24 11:41:53', 1, 'UNPAUSE')
    insert into test values ('2021-09-24 11:43:53', 1, 'UNPAUSE')

SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY
    user ASC,
    time ASC

Query id: ed202dd9-fa74-40eb-9a18-d0582e7eaec6

┌────────────────time─┬─user─┬─event─┐
│ 2021-09-24 11:39:21 │    1 │ PAUSE │
└─────────────────────┴──────┴───────┘
┌────────────────time─┬─user─┬─event───┐
│ 2021-09-24 11:41:53 │    1 │ UNPAUSE │
└─────────────────────┴──────┴─────────┘
┌────────────────time─┬─user─┬─event───┐
│ 2021-09-24 11:43:53 │    1 │ UNPAUSE │
└─────────────────────┴──────┴─────────┘
┌────────────────time─┬─user─┬─event─┐
│ 2021-09-24 11:39:21 │    2 │ PAUSE │
└─────────────────────┴──────┴───────┘
┌────────────────time─┬─user─┬─event───┐
│ 2021-09-24 11:41:53 │    2 │ UNPAUSE │

SELECT
    user,
    arraySum(arrayMap((tx, ex, i) -> if((i > 1) AND (ex = 'UNPAUSE') AND ((e[i - 1]) = 'PAUSE'), tx - (t[i - 1]), 0), t, e, arrayEnumerate(t))) AS sum
FROM
(
    SELECT
        user,
        groupArray(toUnixTimestamp(time)) AS t,
        groupArray(event) AS e
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM test
        ORDER BY
            user ASC,
            time ASC
    )
    GROUP BY user
)

Query id: 0d0e99f3-7a0f-4f5d-a1ce-9b89ef1275a8

┌─user─┬─sum─┐
│    2 │ 152 │
│    1 │ 152 │
└──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thank you! I search documentation of arrayMap. But it so little. Please give me several links. I want to understand how it works.

Comment: This is a good article from Altinity
https://altinity.com/blog/harnessing-the-power-of-clickhouse-arrays-part-3